Unfocus the note entry field when tapped anywhere outside of it on the screen
This is my message field. Currently, I can enter the message here. If I click the next field or outside the entry field, the cursor should unfocus. I need to achieve this behavior. If anyone knows how to solve this issue in .NET MAUI, please provide each step for the implementation.
XML:
<!-- Message Field -->
<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    <!-- Adding a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the Grid to handle taps outside the note editor -->
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapOutsideNoteCommand}" />
</Grid.GestureRecognizers>

<!-- Label indicating the purpose of the note entry -->
<Label Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,20,0,0"
       TextColor="{StaticResource White}" Text="Add a note"
       FontSize="16" FontFamily="Roboto-Medium" IsVisible="{Binding IsMessageVisible}" />

<!-- Border to contain the note editor and character count label -->
<Border Grid.Row="8" Background="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,10,0,0"
        StrokeThickness="0" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5" IsVisible="{Binding IsMessageVisible}">

    <!-- StackLayout to contain the note editor and character count label -->
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        
        <!-- Custom editor for entering the note -->
        <controls:CustomEditor x:Name="noteEditor" Margin="10,10,10,5" BackgroundColor="Transparent" AutoSize="TextChanges" 
                Text="{Binding Message}" TextColor="Black" Placeholder="Enter your note here"
                FontSize="15" FontFamily="Roboto-Regular" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsMessageReadOnly}"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" IsFocused="{Binding IsNoteEditorFocused}"  />

        <!-- Label to display character count -->
        <Label x:Name="characterCountLabel" Margin="0,0,10,5" Text="100 Character" TextColor="{StaticResource Gray600}" 
               FontSize="14" FontFamily="Roboto-Light" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Border>

ViewModel:
// Boolean property to track the focus state of the note editor
private bool _isNoteEditorFocused;

public bool IsNoteEditorFocused 
{ 
    get => _isNoteEditorFocused; 
    set 
    { 
        if (_isNoteEditorFocused != value) 
        { 
            _isNoteEditorFocused = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsNoteEditorFocused)); 
        } 
    } 
}

// Command to handle taps outside the note editor
public ICommand TapOutsideNoteCommand { get; private set; }

// Constructor to initialize the TapOutsideNoteCommand
public YourViewModelConstructor() 
{ 
    TapOutsideNoteCommand = new Command(OnTapOutsideNote); 
}

// Method to unfocus the note editor when tapped outside
private void OnTapOutsideNote() 
{ 
    IsNoteEditorFocused = false; 
}


For Android see this answer: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21053#issuecomment-1997163629

What specifically is not working with your code?

You can check this thread about the issue It is not possible to unfocus an Entry and HideSoftInputOnTapped closes soft keyboard but does not remove focus from Entry.
One of the solution of the issue: put the code below into the MAUI Android MainActivity.cs.
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent? e)
{
    if (e!.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {
        var focusedElement = CurrentFocus;
        if (focusedElement is EditText editText)
        {
            var editTextLocation = new int[2];
            editText.GetLocationOnScreen(editTextLocation);
            var clearTextButtonWidth = 100; // syncfusion clear button at the end of the control
            var editTextRect = new Rect(editTextLocation[0], editTextLocation[1], editText.Width + clearTextButtonWidth, editText.Height);
            //var editTextRect = editText.GetGlobalVisibleRect(editTextRect);  //not working in MAUI, always returns 0,0,0,0
            var touchPosX = (int)e.RawX;
            var touchPosY = (int)e.RawY;
            if (!editTextRect.Contains(touchPosX, touchPosY))
            {
                editText.ClearFocus();
                var inputService = GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
                inputService?.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.WindowToken, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
}

